What are the expected outcomes if I run Cassandra 4.x on RHEL 7?
I need to upgrade my cluster 3.x to 4.x apache cassandra on RHEL 7.9 virtual machine in staging environment. On client site, apache 4.x seem to compatible up RHEL & Centos 7.6, so I'm curious what are the expected outcomes if I run cluster 4.x on RHEL 7.9 in production environment in the future?

Welcome to Stack Overflow! A friendly reminder that this site is for getting help with coding, algorithm, or programming language problems so I voted to have your post moved to DBA Stack Exchange. For future reference, you should post DB admin/ops questions on https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=cassandra. Cheers!

I've answered a somewhat similar question on Stack Exchange a few days ago.
We are not aware of any technical limitations that would prevent Cassandra 4.x from running on RHEL 7.9 but I assume you are asking because it is a very old release. I would be very surprised if there are any other enterprises out there who would choose to deploy software on a platform that will shortly fall out of "full support".
I would also be surprised to hear of any vendors who would bother to do full-scale testing of Cassandra 4.x on RHEL 7 given that it's old. RHEL 8 definitely, but not RHEL 7.
The Apache Cassandra project itself does not perform any platform certification so if you are looking for guarantees, you'll need to engage with a Cassandra vendor that can provide that level of support. Cheers!

If RHEL 8 definitely compatible with Apache Cassandra 4.x, does it work for Apache Cassandra 3.x (specifically 3.11) because I'm upgrading from 3.11 to 4.1, so I need an OS that would be compatible with both versions of Cassandra. Any source/ guidance on this would be much appreciated.
